# TypeError document.getElementByID() ... is null?

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

Can anyone tell me why I might be getting this error?

> "TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null @ line:25"

I am using JavaScript and this is what I have so far inside my `<script>` tags...

```
var initBoard = new Array(new Array(0, 0, 0, 1),
                      new Array(0, 0, 0, 0),
                      new Array(3, 0, 0, 0),
                      new Array(0, 0, 2, 0)
);

function insertData(){
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j <4; j++){
        document.getElementById(i.j).innerHTML = initBoard[i][j];

    }
}
}
```

Below that inside my HTML `<body>` I have this....

```
<table border="2" >
<tr align="center">
<td><div id="00">0</div></td>
<td><div id="01">0</div></td>
<td><div id="02">0</div></td>
<td><div id="03">0</div></td>
</tr>

<tr align="center">
<td><div id="10">0</div></td>
<td><div id="11">0</div></td>
<td><div id="12">0</div></td>
<td><div id="13">0</div></td>
</tr>

<tr align="center">
<td><div id="20">0</div></td>
<td><div id="21">0</div></td>
<td><div id="22">0</div></td>
<td><div id="23">0</div></td>
</tr>

<tr align="center">
<td><div id="30">0</div></td>
<td><div id="31">0</div></td>
<td><div id="32">0</div></td>
<td><div id="33">0</div></td>
</tr>
```

When I try and run this I get that error from above.

I have also tried to just hardcode the "ID" as `'00'` or `'01'` and it still gives me the same error message.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I have looked all over the place and everywhere says basically the same thing and it should be easy, but I cannot get past this.

EDIT: Line 25 is `document.getElementById(i.j).innerHTML = initBoard[i][j];`

Comment: In addition to the answers below, make sure you run all of this in an onload handler.  If run too early, the ids are not yet defined.

Comment: @DrC: Makes a good point. Nothing will be found if the code runs before the elements have been rendered.

Comment: @DrC I think this might be happening, because even with the answers below and me hardcoding in the ID's rather than using i.j I still get the same thing. I can I do this?

Comment: I'll write up a brief answer.

Answer (score 3):

You want to convert the numbers to strings and concatenate them.

```
document.getElementById(i + "" + j).innerHTML = ...
```

---

You had `i.j`, which would take the number referenced by `i`, and ask it for its `j` property, which would return `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah - same issue happened to me once. The problem is that:

ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

So you'll have to replace your way of assigning IDs

Also - your approach of i.j is not correct

Comment: While it's true that HTML 4 doesn't allow IDs that start with a number, HTML5 does allow it. Even in old browsers that don't support HTML5, the DOM selection may still work.

Comment: didn't know about that the html 5 thing - thanks. I did have an issue once with that approach of using ids though but maybe I was doing something more complex involving perhaps jquery.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the code executes after the document is fully loaded.  Something like

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
     <your current code>
},0);
```

As the other posters said, using something like "cell"+i+"_"+j is also a good idea.  I'd put the underscore in so that "111" isn't ambiguous.